# Tableau Calculated Field Help

Tags: tableau

Tableau newbie here would really appreciate some help with a calculated field.

Let's say I have some data:

| Patient ID | Appointment Date |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1/1/2019 |
| 10001 | 4/5/2018 |
| 10001 | 2/3/2021 |
| 10002 | 3/2/2019 |
| 10002 | 3/5/2018 |
| 10003 | 1/1/2019 |
| 10003 | 1/3/2021 |

I want to get the previous appointment date in a separate column, based on the sorted ascending appointment date per patient.

I'd like my output to be:

| Patient ID | Appointment Date | Previous Appointment Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1/1/2019 | 4/5/2018 |
| 10001 | 4/5/2018 | NULL |
| 10001 | 2/3/2021 | 1/1/2019 |
| 10002 | 3/2/2019 | 3/5/2018 |
| 10002 | 3/5/2018 | NULL |
| 10003 | 1/1/2019 | NUll |
| 10003 | 1/3/2021 | 1/1/2019 |

Eventually, I want to get the average time between each appointment.

I've attempted using LOD functions with window functions, but I can't figure out how to partition based on Patient ID (but I could be doing it wrong). Would anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve the output I want? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Above Scenario can be solved using sql query and pass the result to tableau as data source

```sql
with BT1 as (
  Select * from dbo.Tbl_PatientDetail
)
,BT2 as (
  Select * from dbo.Tbl_PatientDetail
)

Select 
  BT1.PatientID,BT1.AppointmentDate
  ,case when (
    Select 
      count(*) 
    from 
      BT2 
    where 
      BT2.AppointmentDate<BT1.AppointmentDate 
      and BT1.PatientID=BT2.PatientID
  )=0 then null
  else (
    Select top 1 
      Bt2.AppointmentDate 
    from 
      Bt2 
    where 
      Bt2.AppointmentDate<BT1.AppointmentDate 
      and BT1.PatientID=BT2.PatientID
  ) end as [Previous Appointment Date] 
from 
  Bt1
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of visits over the total tenure at a clinic would give you average time between visits. Just count the # of records (visits) per each patient. Seems like the actual date of visits is irrelevant.

Psuedo-code:
Total time = current date - initial visit
Total Time/Count(visit_records).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).